# How can we recognise the access token is expired in box api ? Is there any delegate method?

Tags: ios, box-api

Is there any delegate method to find whether the access token is expired or not? How can we get the new access token after it is expired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get new access token use this following code .

```
NSString* refresh =your refresh token;

NSString* clientId =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.clientID];
NSString* clientSecret =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.clientSecret];

ASIFormDataRequest *postParams = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?"]];

[postParams setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[postParams setPostValue:@"refresh_token" forKey:@"grant_type"];
[postParams setPostValue:refresh forKey:@"refresh_token"];
[postParams setPostValue:clientId forKey:@"client_id"];
[postParams setPostValue:clientSecret forKey:@"client_secret"];

[postParams startAsynchronous];
postParams.delegate = self ;
postParams.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"accessToken" forKey:@"id"];

NSLog(@"Url is ---> %@",postParams.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this

-(BOOL)checkExpiredBoxToken
    {

```
    NSLog(@"expire_date %@",[[arrUseraccounts objectAtIndex:[BoxDownloadFileViewControlller getSharedInstance].index] objectForKey:@"expire_date"]);

    NSDate* date1 = [[arrUseraccounts objectAtIndex:[DropboxDownloadFileViewControlller getSharedInstance].index] objectForKey:@"expire_date"];
    NSDate* date2 = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
    double secondsInAnHour = 60;
    NSInteger minsRemaining = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;
    NSLog(@"access token expires in %d mins",minsRemaining);

    if (minsRemaining <2)
    {
        NSLog(@"Time to create new access token");
        [self createNewAccesToken];
    }

    return minsRemaining;
}
```

for Creating New Access token please have a look at 
http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/box/api/box-api/docs/tutorials